# Using data build tool(dbt) and snowflake, how can I check if a column is a date field?

Tags: sql, jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, snowflake-connector

**I'm a Junior so apologies if my explanation isn't that great.**

I've created a macro on dbt to add a default row with defined values or default values based on data type.

What I'm trying to achieve is to check if the column is a datatype `date` field, then it will return the default variable `{{ date_vi }}` which I've defined as `'1900-00-00'`, but I'm getting an error:

`dbt.adapters.snowflake.column.SnowflakeColumn object' has no attribute 'isdate` which tells me there is no `is_date()` which is confusing because `is_date()` works on snowflake normally.

I have now noticed on the dbt docs:

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#column

and the source code on github for snowflake:

https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/blob/main/dbt/adapters/snowflake/column.py

That is_date() isn't actually available with the snowflake adapter, the code I was trying to get working was: `{% elif col.is_date() %}{{ date_vl }}` so I'm wondering what would be the be best way to check if a column is a date `datatype`? Hopefully I explained it enough as I'm still fairly new.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/calogica/dbt-expectations#expect_column_values_to_be_of_type

Or look at their implementation at https://github.com/calogica/dbt-expectations/blob/main/macros/schema_tests/column_values_basic/expect_column_values_to_be_in_type_list.sql for ideas of your custom implementation.